# How to `vue-cli-service serve` programatically

Tags: node.js, vue.js, electron, vue-cli

Using [vue-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/cli-service), **how do I `vue-cli-service serve` programmatically?**

The docs explain how to do that from a npm script, like `"dev": "vue-cli-service serve --port 8080"` inside the *package.json*, however there is no information on how to do it from a script, and preferably without using `exec`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why no `exec`?

Comment: Because it is an Electron app. And I am not sure how `exec` would work in these circumstances. Would the generated EXE/DMG run an actual CLI command? Would it work? If it does, great.